# How to fix "WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR ..." error in Python (or-tools)?

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools

I m trying to solve an optimisation problem using python 3.7.1, spider and    or-tools. For the time being, I want to classify objects in 3 different classes using constraints.

First, I tried to solve it using:

```
    #solver = pywraplp.Solver('LinearExample',
    #                           pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
```

I got some results but not the expected ones because xA xB xC should be 3 binary vectors.
So what, i replaced these two lines to solve the problem as an Integer problem, which appears to me more logical, by:

```
    solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveIntegerProblem',
                          pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```

When I run the code , a window opens with the message: it has stopped working then I receive the following warning :

```
    "An error ocurred while starting the kernel"
    WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
    F0327 09:54:41.733001 3784 map_util.h:126] Check failed:   collection‑>insert(value_type(key, data)).second duplicate key: xA
    *** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

Then I have to close the console 
I don't understand why the problem seems to be x... while it wasn't with 'LinearExample'

Here, the code reproducing the error :

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
  solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveIntegerProblem',
                          pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
  #solver = pywraplp.Solver('LinearExample',
  #                         pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
  # 
  xA = [] # xA[i]=1 if i classified in A, else 0
  xB = [] # xB[i]=1 if i classified in B, else 0
  xC = [] # xC[i]=1 if i classified in C, else 0


  d={'A':[19286.0,23786.0,9822,5054.0,97466.0,728998.0,275708.0,4576.0,67284.0,385582.0,13450.0,43271.0,44601.0,88372.0],
     'B':[12073.0,21563.0,13077.0,6407.0,91850.0,557996.0,206372.0,2812.0,52362.0,244102.0,11225.0,50612.0,49299.0,76099.0],
     'C':[12048.0,42648.0,35491.0,19800.0,117602.0,643498.0,232377.0,5217.0,79200.0,234259.0,19296.0,114048.0,100725.0,130911.0]}
  coeff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


  c={'A':[11503,10638,1984,364,15022,40343,41478,238,3528,51649,5759,5305,7883,301],
     'B':[1783,2047,425,88,2306,6261,6423,51,610,7976,1034,1021,1443,537],
     'C':[128,250,61,15,161,453,461,8,60,566,111,125,161,57]}
  weight = pd.DataFrame(data=c)

  nb_obj=len(coeff['A'])
#variables values : 0 or 1
  for i in range(nb_obj):
      xA.append(solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xA'))
      xB.append(solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xB'))
      xC.append(solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xC'))

  # total weight per class is limited 
  solver.Add(sum(xA*weight.A)<=80000)
  solver.Add(sum(xB*weight.B)<=15000)
  solver.Add(sum(xC*weight.C)<=1500)

  # number of object in each class is limited
  solver.Add(sum(xA)<=3)
  solver.Add(sum(xB)<=6) 
  solver.Add(sum(xC)<=5)

  # 1 object can only belong to a single class
  for i in range (nb_obj):
    solver.Add(xA[i]+xB[i]+xC[i]==1)


  objective = solver.Objective()
  for i in range(nb_obj):
    objective.SetCoefficient(xA[i], coeff.A[i])
    objective.SetCoefficient(xB[i], coeff.B[i])
    objective.SetCoefficient(xC[i], coeff.C[i])
  objective.SetMaximization()

  """Solve the problem and print the solution."""
  result_status = solver.Solve()
  # The problem has an optimal solution.
  assert result_status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL


  print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())
  print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())

  # The objective value of the solution.
  print('Optimal objective value = %d' % solver.Objective().Value())
  print()
  # The value of each variable in the solution.
  for i in range(nb_obj):
    print("obj",i+1," : ",xA[i].solution_value(),xB[i].solution_value(),xC[i].solution_value())



if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Could you help me run the code ?

Comment: At what yoint exactly does that warning occur? Is all that code really necessary to demonstrate the problem (not to solve your original task)? In other words, make sure this is a [mcve]! Also, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The warning is unrelated to the error.

Comment: @KlausD. I m not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: Your output shows a warning in the first line and below that an error that is unrelated to the warning and your real problem. Also you seem to have cut off the most important information: the stack trace.

Comment: Is this what you need ? "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0327 11:42:19.583917 7828 map_util.h:126] Check failed: collection‑>insert(value_type(key, data)).second duplicate key: xA
*** Check failure stack trace: ***

Comment: In the for loop, you’re adding the same named variable multiple times.  Hence the error “duplicate key: xA.”  What is the set of equations and constraints you’re trying to solve?

Comment: @user650654, i just edited with the complete code. I understand what you mean but I find it strange that I do not have the error with the linear resolution. I try to change it

Comment: @user650654, thank you, it was where my problem was coming from.

Comment: @user650654 It seems that the suggestion you made in your last comment solved the asker's problem. Please consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @CodyGray's request, below is working code.  It defines 14 * 3 = 42 variables.  OP's code defined only one (`xA`) or three variables (`xA, xB, xC`) in the for loop and that likely caused the error: `duplicate key: xA`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
  solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveIntegerProblem',
                          pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

  d = {
        'A': [19286.0, 23786.0, 9822.0, 5054.0, 97466.0, 728998.0, 275708.0, 
              4576.0, 67284.0, 385582.0, 13450.0, 43271.0, 44601.0, 88372.0],
        'B': [12073.0, 21563.0, 13077.0, 6407.0, 91850.0, 557996.0, 206372.0,
              2812.0, 52362.0, 244102.0, 11225.0, 50612.0, 49299.0, 76099.0],
        'C': [12048.0, 42648.0, 35491.0, 19800.0, 117602.0, 643498.0, 232377.0,
              5217.0, 79200.0, 234259.0, 19296.0, 114048.0, 100725.0, 130911.0]
      }
  coeff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  c = {
        'A': [11503, 10638, 1984, 364, 15022, 40343, 41478,
              238, 3528, 51649, 5759, 5305, 7883, 301],
        'B': [1783, 2047, 425, 88, 2306, 6261, 6423,
              51, 610, 7976, 1034, 1021, 1443, 537],
        'C': [128, 250, 61, 15, 161, 453, 461,
              8, 60, 566, 111, 125, 161, 57]
      }
  weight = pd.DataFrame(data=c)

  nb_obj=len(coeff['A'])
  xA = [solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xA{:02d}'.format(i)) for i in range(nb_obj)]
  xB = [solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xB{:02d}'.format(i)) for i in range(nb_obj)]
  xC = [solver.IntVar(0.0, 1.0, 'xC{:02d}'.format(i)) for i in range(nb_obj)]

  # total weight per class is limited 
  solver.Add(sum(xA * weight.A) <= 80000)
  solver.Add(sum(xB * weight.B) <= 15000)
  solver.Add(sum(xC * weight.C) <= 1500)

  # number of object in each class is limited
  solver.Add(sum(xA) <= 3)
  solver.Add(sum(xB) <= 6) 
  solver.Add(sum(xC) <= 5)

  # 1 object can only belong to a single class
  for i in range (nb_obj):
    solver.Add(xA[i] + xB[i] + xC[i] == 1)

  objective = solver.Objective()

  for i in range(nb_obj):
    objective.SetCoefficient(xA[i], coeff.A[i])
    objective.SetCoefficient(xB[i], coeff.B[i])
    objective.SetCoefficient(xC[i], coeff.C[i])

  objective.SetMaximization()

  print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())
  print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())

  # Solve the problem and print the solution.
  result_status = solver.Solve()
  # The problem has an optimal solution.
  assert result_status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL

  # The objective value of the solution.
  print('Optimal objective value = %d' % solver.Objective().Value())
  print()
  # The value of each variable in the solution.
  for i in range(nb_obj):
    print("Obj {:02d}:".format(i), xA[i].solution_value(), xB[i].solution_value(), xC[i].solution_value())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The result is:

```
Number of variables = 42
Number of constraints = 20
Optimal objective value = 1840645

Obj 00: 1.0 0.0 0.0
Obj 01: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 02: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 03: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 04: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 05: 0.0 0.0 1.0
Obj 06: 0.0 0.0 1.0
Obj 07: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 08: 1.0 0.0 0.0
Obj 09: 1.0 0.0 0.0
Obj 10: 0.0 1.0 0.0
Obj 11: 0.0 0.0 1.0
Obj 12: 0.0 0.0 1.0
Obj 13: 0.0 0.0 1.0
```